# C++ Encapsulating arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, encapsulation

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I can't find a clear enough answer.

What is the correct way to provide public read-only access to an array member in C++?

if i have a class like the following:

```
   
class Particle
{
    double _position[10];

public:
    double* get_position()
    {
       return _position;
    }
};
```

I guess is really bad to return a pointer to the array, since that means it can be changed at
any time outside of the class, is it enough to return a const pointer instead?

I have seen other questions about the use of arrays in C++, and how is a better option to use vectors, nevertheless I'm really curious about this issue.

As you can see I'm only a C++ noob, sorry if this is a stupid question.

P.D. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You may want to change the design to return an element from the array instead of the huge array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return a const pointer:

```
class Particle
{
    double _position[10];

public:
    const double* get_position() const
    {
       return _position;
    }
};
```

Note that I've also made the member-function const (the second `const`), to tell the compiler that this member-function may be called on `const` `Particle` instances.

*Note: as you've already mentioned, a better solution is to use STL vectors and so on...*

Comment: I´ll try this, but i need to check the use of const in this particular context. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Returning a const* isn't much better, as the caller can just cast the constness away.

Consider providing a const Iterator instead of returning a pointer.  This gives users of your class access to positions without exposing the implementation details.  If you later want to switch from a fixed-length array to a STL container, you can do so with no impact on users of the class.

Comment: Would that also work if i have other array members in the class, for which i desired to provide public access?

Comment: Casting the `const` away is undefined behaviour.  A user can always subvert the desired behaviour if they try hard enough; this is not a reason to use STL over raw arrays...

Comment: @Mario You usually shouldn't mix public and non-public member access in the same class.

Comment: How would a const iterator subvert your point? I can just cast off the constness of the dereferenced value.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a raw array; always prefer `std::array<>` (or [`boost::array<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/array/index.html) if your compiler is not recent enough to ship with a `std::` or `std::tr1::` implementation):

```
class Particle
{
public:
    typedef std::array<double, 10> positions_t;

    Particle() : positions_() { }

    positions_t& get_positions() { return positions_; }
    positions_t const& get_positions() const { return positions_; }

private:
    positions_t positions_;
};
```

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth : The statement "*I have seen other questions about the use of arrays in C++, and how is a better option to use vectors*" doesn't indicate any awareness of `std::array`, which is the real answer here (as opposed to `std::vector`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, return a const pointer to the array (or array element).

```
const double* get_position() const
{
    return _position;
}
```

FWIW, I once implemented a read-only status code within a class using a const reference:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    const int &     err = &errcode;

private:
    int             errcode;
    ...
}
```

(Apologies if the syntax is not quite correct.)
This allows the client of `Foo` to read, but not modify, `Foo::err`, which is a const reference to the actual private error code `Foo::errcode`, which is modifiable by the member functions of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Like any other member that you want to provide access to, you can return a `const` reference to it:

```
const double ( &get_position() const )[10] { return position; }
```

Granted, you might want to use `typedef` to make that easier to read.

Or, since it is an array, you could implement `operator[]`:

```
const double& operator[](std::size_t n) const { return position[n]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three issues / comments:

- Returning an array
- Returning an element
- Returning a `std::vector`

### Returning an array

You can always return a pointer to the array, but when passing arrays, the capacity should always be specified.  Unfortunately, functions can only return one value, so you will have to return "out" parameters from the function:

```
double * get_position(unsigned int& capacity);
// Or
void  get_position(double *& array_pointer, unsigned int& capacity);
```

### Returning an element

You can hide the internal {array} representation by providing a function to return a single element.  This gives an advantage of bounds checking.

```
  double get_one_position(unsigned int index)
  {
    double result = 0.0;
    if (index >= MAX_CAPACITY)
    {
       // Errror handling
    }
    else
    {
      result = _position[index];
    }
    return result;
  }
```

### Returning a `std::vector`

In C++ prefer `std::vector` to an array.  Your issue is one reason to switch.  The `std::vector` can be passed to and returned from a method.  Also, the `std::vector` maintains its own capacity variables, so there is no need to pass a capacity along with an array pointer.

```
  std::vector<double> _position(10);
  std::vector<double> get_positions(void)
  {
     return _position;
  }
```

### Summary

I suggest you first try to hide the array implementation from the clients or users.  If that cannot be done, prefer using `std::vector` to an array.  Lastly use an array.

When returning an array, **always** accompany it with a capacity variable.